# Wordpress Plugin ID post

Tags: wordpress

I should make a plugin that prints the ids of the blog articles on the page of the same (therefore in the wp back end), can anyone tell me the code to use? Yes, that's easy enough but 
I'm a beginner. Thank you

**Here is my code**

```
 add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

 function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'Marco plugin', 'manage_options', 
        'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
 }



function test_init(){

    if ( have_posts() ) : 
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                    // Display post content
                    echo the_title();
            endwhile; 
    else:
            echo "Sorry";
            endif; 

}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you want?

Comment: Use a wpQuery to fetch the posts and loop that

Comment: i use a wpQuery but does not find articles in the blog

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_ID() to display particular post id. and you can make a function like

```
function yourFunction( $content ) {    
    if( is_single() ) {
        $content .= get_the_ID();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'yourFunction' );
```

Comment: returns nothing, white screen

Comment: https://ibb.co/p1L0YRx Its working fine. Please enable debugging in wordpress and see if there is any other error.

Comment: I want the id to appear in the back end, on the plugin screen itself